# Filling in a matrix in java

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I need to fill in a matrix (a table) for my java assignment.  I'm not sure where to start could someone please help me set it up.
Thank you

Comment: `int[][] matrix = new int[5][6]; for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) matrix[i][j] = i*j;` and then `for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) { for(int j = 0; j < 6; j++) { System.out.println("" + matrix[i][j]); } System.out.println(""); }`

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A resource, not a help forum. It's for specific questions about coding that can have definite correct answers, not a place to ask open-ended questions seeking broad overviews, tutorials, introductory info, or general pointers about getting started. Please read the [Tour] page and the following advice on asking good questions: [[ask]], [[Writing the perfect question](http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints)].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int [][] matrix = new int[10][20];
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < 20; j++) {
        // read information from somewhere
        matrix[i][j] = information;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int [][] arr = new int[x][y];
for(int i = 0; i < x; i++) {        // it will run you through the lines 
    for(int j = 0; j < y; j++) {    // this will run you through each cell in the raw selected
        arr[i][j] = <the thing you want to fill here> ;
    }
}
```

you can look at a matrix as an array of arrays
the **first** `for` is to run trough the array
the **second** is `for` the cells in each array